# Django модель с выбором опции ввода

Tags: python, django

[image: таблица]

Нужно сделать модель для такой таблицы. Слева наименование услуги, справа ИЛИ

1) минимальная стоимость, ед. измерения и кол-во

ИЛИ

2)текст, если стоимость определить невозможно.

Хочу понять как сделать так, чтобы в админке можно было выбирать что вводить для данной модели. Ну или вообще как реализовать логику для вот такой штуки.

Comment: Multitable наследование наверное, или genericforeignkey. Админку в любом случае кастомизировать придется

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете сделать модель с наименованием услуги, ценой, количеством и текстовым описанием. Также добавьте логическое свойство, которое будет отображать стандартная ли это услуга. При отображении на странице с помощью if в шаблонизаторе стройте разные строки таблицы в зависимости от того, стандартная это услуга или нет.